# load new page-Android XML

Tags: android

I have three xml layout pages, 1.welcome screen (with "next >>" button) and clicking on next button should bring second page 2.welcome page with ("register" button) this takes to another window/page 3. with name and other details. I have all the three pages GUI built i.e the xml file , how to put them all together and get them working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.welcome);



Button submit_figc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.skipbutton);//to load figc

submit_figc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Figc.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
});}}
----------
Here is Figc
------------

package com.appiction.lifeguard;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Figc extends Activity{

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.figc);
}}
```